# How to Select Non Contiguous lines in SMSS 17.9

Tags: sql-server, localdb

In Microsoft text products like Word and One Note, one can select multiple lines that are not next to each other by holding down ALT and selecting said lines. Is there a way to do this SQL without constantly having to cut and paste thing around? For example:

[image]

I want to run both queries at the same time but cannot without moving them next to each other

Comment: Alt + Select text?

Comment: @Sami - that selects the same columns on contiguous lines https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrgMV.png not arbitrary non contiguous text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMSS 17.X is based on Visual Studio 2015 Shell. SSMS 18.x uses [Visual Studio 2017 15.9.11 shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#whats-new-in-180).

You need to upgrade to get multi caret support. In the most recent version(s) of SSMS and since  [Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improving-your-productivity-in-the-visual-studio-editor/) you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and select non contiguous areas with the mouse.

Below screenshot is using SSMS 18.5

[image]

Comment: Ah, it would seem I can't do that with SSM 17.9 @Martin Smith

Comment: This is a new feature to Visual Studio so new to SSMS (on which it is based)  It's worth upgrading anyway to take advantage of other new features - such as per operator timings shown in actual execution plan diagrams

Comment: I Actually have 18.5 but the team I am interning for uses 17.9 @Martin Smith

Comment: you're out of luck then.. This is a new feature to VS so not available in versions of SSMS based on older versions of the Visual Studio shell from before this feature being developed

Comment: Unrelated question, on SMSS, can you stop the left Object Explorer panel from collapsing after every refresh so you dont need to dig through all the files/dbs to find what you were looking for all over again? @Martin Smith

Comment: you can just refresh specific folders on the tree so it doesn't collapse the whole thing. Probably it will still collapse the folder you refreshed though, can't remember